# How to call javascript function with Python Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I want to call MapITRFtoWgs84() function multiple times, actually giving input from a text file and write the output to the another text file? I think Selenium is appropirate tool for my goal. How can I do that? Here is the photo of the calling function from chrome console: [ss of chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pKvy.png)

Comment: Which programming language are you using

Comment: java or python is ok for me

Comment: what happens if you do driver.execute_script("MapITRFtoWgs84()") or driver.execute_script("$.MapITRFtoWgs84()")  or driver.execute_script("document.MapITRFtoWgs84()")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   driver.execute_script("MapITRFtoWgs84()") or 
   driver.execute_script("$.MapITRFtoWgs84()") or 
   driver.execute_script("document.MapITRFtoWgs84()")
```

Try any of the above methods , it depends on whether jquery is exported in the page . Else you will get $ not defined error .